# LibGdx AdMob Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I've followed this tutorial: [AdMob integration for LibGDX Android projects](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads2.php) and occured a problem. Everything compiles just fine but I don't see a banner. Any ideas?

LogCat

```
01-14 22:33:22.453 3138-3138/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-14 22:34:22.453 3138-3138/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-14 22:34:22.463 3138-3138/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

AndroidLauncher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {

private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    View gameView = initializeForView(new IhateSpace(this), config);
    setupAds();

    // Define the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, params);

    setContentView(layout);


}

public void setupAds() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);


    adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000); // black
    // adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // transparent



}

@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            builder.addTestDevice("C0F358A60027941F44126ED98B0B67BF");
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            adView.loadAd(ad);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void hideBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
}
}
```

IhateSpace class

```
public class IhateSpace extends Game {

//Virtual Screen size and Box2D Scale(Pixels Per Meter)
public static final int V_WIDTH = 960; //10 800 1920
public static final int V_HEIGHT = 540  ; //6 480 1080
public static final float PPM = 0.005f;

private ImageProvider imageProvider;

public SpriteBatch batch;
public BitmapFont font;

private AdsController adsController;

public IhateSpace(AdsController adsController){
    this.adsController = adsController;
}


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    imageProvider = new ImageProvider();


    // Use libGDX's default Arial font
    font = new BitmapFont();
    Settings.load();

    adsController.showBannerAd();
    //this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this, imageProvider, adsController));


}



@Override
public void render () {
    super.render(); // important!

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
}
}
```

Only red screen shows up. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I managed to change something. Now i get:

```
01-15 01:13:37.213 31032-31032/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/AdCheck: APS: blockAdView: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{2d5c9d6a G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
```

It's like:

```
01-15 01:53:00.083 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click!  <---- Banner hided
01-15 01:53:06.673 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click!  <---- Banner showed (theoretically, it doesn't show up really)
01-15 01:53:06.673 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/AdCheck: APS: blockAdView: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{2da90ab0 G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
01-15 01:53:07.623 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click!  <---- Banner hided
01-15 01:53:08.223 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click!  <---- Banner showed (theoretically, it doesn't show up really)
01-15 01:53:08.223 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/AdCheck: APS: blockAdView: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{2da90ab0 G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
01-15 01:53:45.813 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-15 01:53:45.813 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-15 01:54:45.813 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
01-15 01:54:45.813 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-15 01:55:08.473 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click! <---- Banner hided
01-15 01:55:09.173 2975-3038/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click! <---- Banner showed (theoretically, it doesn't show up really)
01-15 01:55:09.173 2975-2975/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/AdCheck: APS: blockAdView: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{2da90ab0 G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}}
```

Full log:

```
01-15 12:09:31.590 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Hwaps: APS: version is 2.3
01-15 12:09:31.590 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/ApsUserFeedback: APS: User feedback is not supported
01-15 12:09:31.590 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/ApsLdfGameIdentify: APS: Ldf game identify is not supported
01-15 12:09:31.590 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/ApsLtrGameIdentify: APS: Ltr game identify is not supported
01-15 12:09:31.610 23017-23066/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Toggle: Click!
01-15 12:09:31.610 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/AdCheck: APS: blockAdView: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView{6286df3 G.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ffmpeg
01-15 12:09:31.730 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/ffmpeg
01-15 12:09:31.740 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-pn-realvideo
01-15 12:09:31.740 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg
01-15 12:09:31.740 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
01-15 12:09:31.750 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
01-15 12:09:31.750 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
01-15 12:09:31.750 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
01-15 12:09:31.770 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
01-15 12:09:31.780 23017-23165/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
01-15 12:09:31.820 23017-23169/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: No such thread id for suspend: 27
01-15 12:09:31.890 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 37 (eng.jenkins-arm64) (code 199992)
01-15 12:09:31.920 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/LibraryLoader: Loading: webviewchromium
01-15 12:09:31.920 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 5 ms (timestamps 8049-8054)
01-15 12:09:31.920 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
01-15 12:09:31.930 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
01-15 12:09:31.930 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-15 12:09:31.950 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-15 12:09:31.950 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:31.980 23017-23189/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
01-15 12:09:31.990 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
01-15 12:09:31.990 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=62 off=155148 len=3312
01-15 12:09:32.000 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:63 off:228796 len:643667
01-15 12:09:32.080 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Starting ad request.
01-15 12:09:32.590 23017-23198/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-15 12:09:32.590 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
01-15 12:09:32.590 23017-23198/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-15 12:09:32.760 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:32.770 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
01-15 12:09:32.780 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:32.780 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:33.310 23017-23228/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:SkFontConfigInterface_android.cpp(227)] ---- system font and fallback font files specify a duplicate font /system/fonts/NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf, skipping the second occurrence
01-15 12:09:33.370 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-15 12:09:33.370 23017-23228/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:SkUtilsArm.cpp(179)] Device supports ARM NEON instructions!
01-15 12:09:33.560 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:33.560 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
01-15 12:09:33.570 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:33.570 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-15 12:09:33.580 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
01-15 12:09:33.590 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
01-15 12:09:33.590 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:60000
01-15 12:09:33.590 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System.out: [socket][0] connection csi.gstatic.com/173.194.113.119:443;LocalPort=58796(60000)
01-15 12:09:33.590 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System.out: [CDS]connect[csi.gstatic.com/173.194.113.119:443] tm:60
01-15 12:09:33.620 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
01-15 12:09:33.620 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
01-15 12:09:33.650 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System.out: [socket][/10.116.245.132:58796] connected
01-15 12:09:33.650 23017-23251/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
01-15 12:09:33.810 23017-23017/com.reiz3n.ihatespace.android I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
adView.invalidate();
```

to your show function.

Comment: After that you might want to go and rethink your life for installing banner ads in your game in this day and age. It has so many drawbacks and you will make virtually no money from it.

Comment: Invalidate doesn't change a thing. And regarding banner, It's one of ads and it just fits my app perfectly... Added full log to main post.

Answer (score 0):

I fought against this error for few more hours. I got banner to work, but it disappeared later, showed once, and disappeared again. Only thing that worked in 100% was changing ad network to StartApp, so if anyone occur same, frustrating problem I highly recommend changing ad provider, instead of wasting 2 days like me.